# Using gulp-load-tasks in a gulpfile

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a project that was using Grunt. I am moving it to use Gulp. My Grunt implementation was like this:

```
gruntfile.js
/e2e
  page.e2e.js
/tasks
  e2e.js
  /configuration
    clean.js
    concat.js
```

I have this approach working in Grunt. However, I now want to mimic this approach in Gulp. At this time, I have the following in Gulpfile.js

**gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var tasks = require('gulp-load-tasks')('tasks');
```

Then, in e2e.js, I have the following:

**e2e.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rimraf = require('gulp-rimraf');

gulp.task('clean, function(cb) {
  console.log('here');
});
```

When I run `gulp` from the command-line, I get an error that says: "Error: Task e2e can't support dependencies that is not an array of strings." I'm not sure how to fix this. I haven't even gotten to the part where I'm putting the definition of the clean task in /tasks/configuration/clean.js.

Thank you for any insights you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the code:

```
gulp.task('clean, function(cb) {
  console.log('here');
});
```

You forgot to close the string `'clean`.

Answer (score 0):

Running `gulp` from the command line should technically return nothing / error out since you have no default task defined (is shorthand for `gulp default`).

With regards to the actual message you are getting something isn't checking out with task e2e when gulp-load-tasks is pulling it in.

In regards to that structure i dunno if i'd use gulp-load-tasks, instead try:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir

oh and also to load your gulp modules (if any) check out:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load-plugins

Need more info, what's in your e2e file?

Comment: also you are missing a comma on the end of the clean task name.